# How to show a gif image in Windows RT?

Tags: c#, image, windows-8, windows-runtime, gif

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Display an Animated GIF in a Metro App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756324/display-an-animated-gif-in-a-metro-app)

I am trying to show gif images in my WinRT app. My current solution is to use a server side converter to convert the images to png, and then load them into an Image control. I have limited bandwidth and would prefer to do it in-app. I used .Net Image Tools to do this on Windows Phone, but it does not appear to be available for Windows RT. I cannot show the images in a WebView because I need to show another element over the image.

Comment: Please reopen this question. I am not trying to show a gif image. This isn't even close to a duplicate of the other question.