# How to show a gif image in WinRT?

Tags: c#, image, windows-8, windows-runtime, gif

I am trying to show **NON ANIMATED** gif images in my WinRT app. My current solution is to use a server side converter to convert the images to png, and then load them into an Image control. I have limited bandwidth and would prefer to do it in-app. I used .Net Image Tools to do this on Windows Phone, but it does not appear to be available for Windows RT. I cannot show the images in a WebView because I need to show another element over the image. I know this is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213042/how-to-show-a-gif-image-in-windows-rt), but that was closed by users who thought it was a duplicate of a question asking about showing animated gifs. My question is how to show **NON ANIMATED** gifs, and I can't seem to delete the old question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the gif directly in XAML within the `<Image>` element. There is no need to convert it. Just set the `Source` attribute to the image.

Comment: I cannot believe I didn't think gifs were supported in Metro for this long. I guess I see why other users thought I meant animated gifs.