# Animations in Windows 8

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Display an Animated GIF in a Metro App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756324/display-an-animated-gif-in-a-metro-app)

I am creating a windows 8 app and my client has requested that I include animated gifs but since they aren't supported I'm a little stuck. I've read that only some of the devices will support flash files so that's not an option for me either.

What other animation types are supported by windows 8?  I'm guessing that Silverlight animations are supported but is this really my only option? It's so limited if it is.

Comment: what kind of winrt app are you writing?

Comment: You can use the same methods you would use for Windows 7 applications.  If you are talking about `.NET Windows Store Applications` then you need to mention this.  All Windows 8 devices will support flash, Windows RT isn't Windows 8, its important to clarify what your talking about exactly.