# Do Windows 8 JavaScript apps support GIF images?

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8

Do Windows 8 JavaScript apps support GIF images?
If so, how can I display the GIF image?

I tried this below code but it wasn't working:

```
<img id="backround" src="images/header.gif" />
```

**Update**

I don't need a C# app. I need a JavaScript app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display an Animated GIF in a Metro App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756324/display-an-animated-gif-in-a-metro-app)

Comment: Sorry Sorry . it's gif only

Comment: @MikeRobinson .That is c# app .I need javascript app

Comment: Have you considered png ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The support file types are listed here in the remarks [section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh466114.aspx):

Gif should work but not animated gifs.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, since the WWAHost supports all the rendering features Internet Explorer does, it can also render GIF, even animated ones.

If it doesn't work for you, check if the file is included in the solution and the generated package. Also you can try adding a leading "/" to the path.